# Constructor and methods in an enum

Tags: c#, enums

I'd like to know if there's a way to include a constructor and methods in an `enum` in C#. I had something like this in mind:

```
public enum ErrorCode
{
    COMMONS_DB_APP_LEVEL("Application problem: {0}", "Cause of the problem"),
    COMMONS_DB_LOW_LEVEL("Low level problem: {0}", "Cause of the problem"),
    COMMONS_DB_CONFIGURATION_PROBLEM("Configuration problem: {0}", "Cause of the problem");

    private String message;
    private String[] argumentDescriptions;

    private ErrorCode(String message, String[] argumentDescriptions)
    {
        this.message = message;
        this.argumentDescriptions = argumentDescriptions;
    }

    public String[] GetArgumentDescriptions()
    {
        return argumentDescriptions;
    }

    public String GetKey()
    {
        return argumentDescriptions();
    }

    public String GetMessage()
    {
        return message;
    }
}
```

Obviously, I cannot write an `enum` like this. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You can create a `class`...

Comment: This post lacks so much information! What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not what enums are for. Use a class instead. Here's a quick example:

```
public class ErrorCode
{
    public static readonly ErrorCode COMMONS_DB_APP_LEVEL = new ErrorCode("Application problem: {0}", "Cause of the problem");
    public static readonly ErrorCode COMMONS_DB_LOW_LEVEL = new ErrorCode("Low level problem: {0}", "Cause of the problem");
    public static readonly ErrorCode COMMONS_DB_CONFIGURATION_PROBLEM = new ErrorCode("Configuration problem: {0}", "Cause of the problem");

    private String message;
    private String[] argumentDescriptions;

    private ErrorCode(String message, params String[] argumentDescriptions)
    {
        this.message = message;
        this.argumentDescriptions = argumentDescriptions;
    }

    public String[] GetArgumentDescriptions()
    {
        return argumentDescriptions;
    }

    public String GetKey()
    {
        // Need to implement this yourself
    }

    public String GetMessage()
    {
        return message;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(ErrorCode.COMMONS_DB_APP_LEVEL.GetMessage(), "Foo"); 
// Application problem: Foo
```

A few more suggestions:

- Names like `COMMONS_DB_APP_LEVEL` do not conform to Microsoft's [General Naming Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
- You should generally use [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) rather than methods like `GetMessage` (Unless your method takes a long time to execute or involves side effects).
- You should be careful about returning the array from `GetArgumentDescriptions` as it allows other code to directly set any elements of the array (even though they can't directly assign a new array). Consider using something like [`Array.AsReadOnly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53kysx7b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You need to simply use the class and create the enum inside the class and also use the description if you want for every enum value.

```
public class ErrorCode
    {
        public enum ErrorCode
        {
            [Description("Application level problem")]    
            COMMONS_DB_APP_LEVEL,
            [Description("Database level problem")]
            COMMONS_DB_LOW_LEVEL,
            [Description("Configuration level problem")]
            COMMONS_DB_CONFIGURATION_PROBLEM
        }
        private String message;
        private String[] argumentDescriptions;

        private ErrorCode(String message, String[] argumentDescriptions)
        {
            this.message = message;
            this.argumentDescriptions = argumentDescriptions;
        }

        public String[] GetArgumentDescriptions()
        {
            return argumentDescriptions;
        }

        public String GetKey()
        {
            return argumentDescriptions();
        }

        public String GetMessage()
        {
            return message;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

because you must use classes instead of enums for writing code something like that. if you are more information for enums you can visit [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx) link.